# Variance sensitivity of dataset with scaling

Tags: machine-learning, variance, pca, standardization

What I have is 3 datasets scaled with `RobustScaler`, `MinMaxScaler` and `StandardScaler`. However I do not have the original dataset. I have read that especially `MinMaxScaler` may alter the variance of the dataset.

What I want to do is somehow check if these scalings are valid or if they have a negative influence in my original dataset.

What I have thought so far is to do PCA on all 3 datasets and check the variance explainability of the principal components. If for all 3 the explainability is the same then we can assume that the data cloud has just been scaled and has not had an important change in its formation. If two have the same and one not, then maybe the latter is a problem.

Would this be a valid course of action?

Comment: Without a reference to what those pieces of software do it is hard to answer but in general I would expect scaling to alter variance.

Comment: @mdewey is correct.  A bunch of scaled versions of datasets, where the scalings are performed separately for each variable, can tell you exactly *nothing* about the original scales.